# fire event in the angular2 component

Tags: angular

I have 2 components:

```
app.component
site.component
```

I would like to catch event from site component in app component.
But site component rendered from router(when I click on some link)
Now in the site component I have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sites-list',
  templateUrl: './sites-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sites-list.component.css'],
  outputs: ['counterChange'],

})
export class Sites implements OnInit {

  public counterChange = new EventEmitter();
```

and in the tmplate:

```
 <button type="submit" (click)="check(url.value);">Go</button>
```

So, How can I catch this event in the app component. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components that do not lie within a parent/child hierarchy typically communicate via an injectable service. Something like this (I didn't test this code):

```
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    public notifierSubject:Subject = new Subject();

    public notify(something:any) {
       this.notifierSubject.next(something);
    }
}
```

In Component 1, the sender:

```
 constructor(myService:MyService) {
 }

 check(value) {
    this.myService.notify(value);
 }
```

In Component 2, the receiver:

```
 constructor(myService:MyService) {
     myService.notifierSubject.subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });
 }
```

In this example I picked a `Subject` from RxJS. Of course, you are free to pick whatever you want. Everything you can subscribe to, should do the job.